# Using "PHP Cache" without Composer

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php

I found a PHP caching library that I'd like to use in CodeIgniter, but the docs only have instructions for installing / using with composer: http://www.php-cache.com/en/latest/

I inherited a project on a server that doesn't have Composer. Ideally I would like to use it without Composer. Does anyone have any knowledge of how to load this without it?

Answer (score 1):

well, you could download the package itself and add it to your Codeignitter libraries autoload (if that's possible, sorry, dont know too much of CodeIgnitter). Though if i'd be you i'd go into Composer, it is revolutionary for php apps and you're loosing out so much by not using it... just composer init in main app folder & make sure that your CI is reading the autoloaded classes (i bet you'll find some tutorial for that)

by download I mean download and require in your php files where you're using it!